Diagonal inches of a device in android compose
I am trying to calculate tthe diagonal inches of my device in Android with compose but
I can not get the correct value
I have this information available in Android with compose:
val heightPx = currentWindowSize().height
val widthPx = currentWindowSize().width
val density = displayMetrics.densityDpi

I am trying to calculate the diagonal size of my device in inches, but I am not getting the correct value :(
fun calculateDiagonalInchesFromDensity(
    width: Int,
    height: Int,
    density: Double
): Double {
    require(density > 0)

    val widthInInches = width.toDouble() / density
    val heightInInches = height.toDouble() / density
    val diagonal = sqrt(widthInInches.pow(2) + heightInInches.pow(2))

    return (diagonal * 100.0).roundToInt() / 100.0
}

As an example a Pixel 6 with a diagonal of 6.4", shows a result of 6.27"
Thanks in advance

The calculation is correct. When I run this on a Pixel 6 emulator it uses a density of 420dpi (which results in 6.27"). But the physical Pixel 6 actually has 411dpi (resulting in 6.4"). I don't know why the emulator says it would be a 6.4" display when the pixels and dpi only provide for 6.27"... I observed this for other emulators as well.

@tyg the main reason is to provide integer values and a simple way of approximately evaluate the scaling of the screen. Back in the days (like 10 years ago) there would be very few values, and we would just use low, medium, high, xhigh... We would then express the size of things on the screen based on the ratio from medium. Low is 0.75, high is 1.5, ... which would help get similarly size assets on all devices, without dealing with complex cases.

Thanks for the information above. I have tried a new way to calculate it BUT in a real Pixel6 device, not an emulator.
val xdpi = displayMetrics.xdpi -> 409.432 
val ydpi = displayMetrics.ydpi -> 411.891

It is a value around 411
If I calculate the diagonalInches using this value instead of the density I get 6,4inches

Just out of curiosity what's the result when you run the code from your question on the physical Pixel 6? I assume it is also 6.4", right?

No, If I run the code of my first question in a physical Pixel 6 I get 6'27 inches

densityDpi is not meant to be the exact density of the screen. There are a set of fixed value constants, see in the documentation:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics#densityDpi
xdpi and ydpi are more accurate values.

Since xdpi and ydpi also provide 420 for the Pixel 6 emulator the result wouldn't change. The issue seems to be with the emulator. The Pixel 6 emulator claims to be 6.4" with a resolution of 1080x2400 and 420dpi. Do the math, it doesn't add up.

Hi @tyg, again densityDpi is not meant to be exact. All the valid constant values are listed in the linked documentation (with values like 400 and 420, one can assume that the device returns the value that makes the most sense, which would be 420). As confirmed by the OP in https://stackoverflow.com/a/79220976/671543, xdpi and ydpi give accurate values.

one way to look at this is also to consider that the pixels are not actually perfectly square, and have no reason to be an integer fraction of an inch. densityDpi is useful in many cases, just not in any that requires accuracy (and 411 is also not as accurate as it could get)

Sorry, my first comment didn't make that sufficiently clear: I wasn't talking about what the APIs return, the values I cited are the ones listed in the "Virtual Device Configuration" dialog used to create new emulators in Android Studio. And the values already doesn't make sense there, so I'm not that surprised that the APIs also don't return plausible values. For the physical device at least xdpi and ydpi seem to return usable values, whereas on the emulator the values don't make sense either.

got it, thanks for clarifying
